# Migrate bookmarks from Firefox to Safari

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, safari, bookmarks

I have a Time Machine backup from a previous Snow Leopard installation where my Firefox bookmarks reside somewhere. I want to use them in Safari in my new Lion Installation. The problem is that I forgot to export bookmarks. I had a look at the Application Support Firefox folder at the bookmarks folder but only a .jsod or so file can be found there and this can not be imported into Safari. I wonder how would I be able to import them into  Safari.

Comment: Note that `mac` refers to the hardware. You need to tag your questions `osx`.

Comment: Could it be as simple as putting your old Firefox profile on your new installation, installing Firefox, and then either exporting bookmarks or using XMarks to sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Open Firefox. If you have uninstalled it, try using **Portable Firefox**.
2. From Bookmark Library ~> Backup and Import ~> Restore, choose that .jsod file.
3. From Bookmark Library ~> Backup and Import ~> Export HTML, export bookmarks as HTML.
4. Open Safari. From File ~> Import Bookmarks, import the exported HTML file.

You can replace steps 3 and 4 by installing [Xmarks](http://download.xmarks.com/download/macosx_10_6) and syncing bookmarks with it (it'll return no bug).